# How to load product's swatch info through PHP script which is showing on listing page and product detail page?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, magento2.4.5, configurable-swatches

Does anyone suggest how to load the product's swatch info through the PHP script which is showing on the product detail page and category pages?

[image]

```
$config_product_id = 12;
$configProductObject = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface');
$configProductObject->load($config_product_id);
```

Have looked at this provider but returned a list of swatch attributes for the product.

```
$magentoSwatchesProvider = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Swatches\Model\SwatchAttributesProvider');
$swatchArray = $magentoSwatchesProvider->provide($configProductObject);
```

Tried to use this public method but gives a compressed configuration for js which also requires some change.

```
$magentoSwatchesConfigurable = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable');
$magentoSwatchesConfigurable->setProduct($configProductObject);
$jsonConfigString = $magentoSwatchesConfigurable->getJsonConfig();
```

Any public method or any API endpoint also would be good.

Need attribute data `attribute_id`, `code`, `option_id`, `option_label` for a given product.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

public function __construct(Configurable $typeConfigurable, Product $_product) 
{
     $this->typeConfigurable = $typeConfigurable;
     $this->_product = $_product;
}

$product = $this->_product->load($productId); //Pass Product id here

$configurableAttributes = $this->typeConfigurable->getConfigurableAttributes($product);
```

[image]

**For reference you can review this Magento file :**

```
vendor/magento/module-swatches/Model/SwatchAttributesProvider.php
```